# Can't understand error in this program for checking automorphic no.?

Tags: c++, c

```
int a = 0, b, c, e, n = 25;
e = n;

while(n!=0)
{
  n=n/10;
  a++;
}

printf("%d",a);

b = e * e;
c = b % (pow(10, a));
if(c==e)
  printf("automorphic");
```

For the line

```
c=b%(pow(10,a));
```

the compiler shows an error:

```
invalid operands of types `int' and `double' to binary `operator%'
```

Answer (score 7):

pow returns a double, and you can't use % on doubles.

Comment: True. Or to be extremely pedantic. You can't use % on floating point numbers in c++. I know at least one other language which define % on its  float type. But that is kind of off-topic :}

Answer (score 3):

pow returns a double, which you cannot use as operator for the %.

Try:

```
c=b%((int)pow(10,a));
```

instead.

Comment: honestly, MTilsted below gave the better advice.

Answer (score 2):

As per other answers: `pow` introduces doubles into your program, and then you hvave to convert them back to ints.

Best to *avoid* the problem, then:

```
int a = 1;
while(n!=0)
{
   n=n/10;
   a *= 10;
}
a /= 10;

b=e*e;
c=b%a;
```

(Edit) I marked a line "Fishy" because what happens with `n=0..9`? You probably need

```
while (n >= 10)
   ..
```

(Edit again, sigh) Sorry -- above edit is wrong, you need the total number of digits. `a` needs adjusting after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator can be operated only with integers. `pow` function returns a `double` and that's why you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ the modulus operator (`%`) is limited to integers. You can use `fmod (...)` for floating-point modulus but you still need to match types to use that. So you are going to have to cast one of your variables or expressions no matter which solution you chose to use; I would use integer modulus personally.

This is in contrast to languages like Java and C#, which allow you to have an integer on one side of the modulus operator and a float on the other with no problems. This can be a source of portability headaches when porting from other languages into C.

Answer (score 0):

**The code can be corrected as:**

```
int a = 0, b, c, e, n = 25;
e = n;
while(n!=0)
{
  n=n/10;
  a++;
}
printf("%d",a);
b = e * e;
/*
 call to pow() function returns a double value and b is an integer type variable.
 For any operation (here, modular division) the operands must be of same type.
 So, the double value returned from call to pow() function must be explicitly 
 casted to int type as shown in the code below. Also, the first argument to pow()
 must to be double (or, float) type. Here, 10 is integer type, correct it as 10.0. 
 The result will be fine.
*/
c = b % (int)(pow(10.0, a));
if(c==e)
printf("automorphic");
```